# Who is making gestures (in this song)?

Tags: meaning

I am talking about the children's song entitled [고향길](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkoDGuWBUqI). The lyrics (the second part, actually) goes like this:

> 내 고향 가는 길 들국화 피는 길
>   구비구비 산길 따라 꽃바람 일고
>   산마루의 흰구름 어서 오라고
>   고개 넘다 멈추어서 손짓하는 길

Looking at the last line, I had been thinking of a **child**, going over a hill, stopping and looking back for a brief moment, and making gestures to his/her friends saying "come on", and probably repeating this set of actions for several times along the road that leads to his/her hometown (`고개 넘다 멈추어서 손짓하다`). But if this is the case, the phrase `산마루의 흰구름` has nothing to go with it, and the meaning seems incomplete.

Therefore, I thought of two ways out of this problem. Firstly, it is possible that `흰구름` is part of the phrase quoted by `라고`. I.e., the child is *asking* *the* *cloud* to come along with him/her. Secondly, it might be that the cloud, `흰구름`, is the one doing all these actions of `고개 넘다 멈추어서 손짓하다`. I.e., the **cloud**, rather than the **child**, is the subject of these verbs. But both these interpretations seem strange to me (the second is definitely stranger).

**My question**: Is my reasoning on the right track, or am I completely missing the point? Which interpretation do you think is the right one, or is the poet deliberately being ambiguous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

흰구름 is doing so. 흰구름 is the one doing all the actions of 어서 오라고 고개 넘다 멈추어서 손짓하다.

It is just that you are unfamiliar with a few literary expressions. You can find such expressions including "고개 넘는 구름" and "구름이라도 쉬어 넘는 고개" on the Web. Such *personification* is found especially in literature.

You should consider that 손짓하다 is also connected to 오라고: "오라고 손짓하다" because the verb, 손짓하다, requires both 에게 and -고. We can say that "a (pro)noun + 에게 (at/to)" is omitted, and the noun is highly likely to be the speaker as she/he is describing the road. Of course, it may be other people on the road if the speaker is just the observer.

In addition, there is a hint about who can tell someone to hurry and come: 흰구름 is at/around the ridge (산마루).

Therefore, 흰구름 is making gestures at the speaker or other people on the road.

The third and last lines are understood as "산마루에 있는 흰 구름이 고개를 넘다가 멈추어서 어서 오라고 손짓하는 길."

Comment: Thank you so much. Indeed I have never seen expressions like `고개 넘는 구름` and `구름이라도 쉬어 넘는 고개`. Given these, the interpretation that the cloud is doing all these now makes perfect sense.